# Get method's return type of another class without extend

Tags: java

I have seen lot of code where class's method return type is another class's type without extend.

I want to understand how a class can afford or produce a method whose return type is another class's type without any relation ship in between them.

If one extends other then I think there is some relationship among them but how about that when there is no relation.

In case of interfaces, when we dont implements, it creates a anonymous which implements that interface and then things get done. But how about in this case ? Is it a same rule getting followed ..?

Consider below code, Is it possible..? If yes then HOW and WHY..?

```
    Class A {


    }


    Class B{


    public A returntypeofA(){

        return new A();

    }

 }
```

Comment: Here's a counter-question: why do you think it is not possible?

Comment: It's really unclear what you mean. Why *shouldn't* a method in class `B` be able to declare a method with a return type of `A`? To give a concrete example, do you think it's odd that `String.length()` can return an `int`?

Comment: @JonSkeet, Lets take a example, How a factory can produce a type without having its blue print, unless there is a relationship ? Doesnt make sense right....?

Comment: @Joy: what do you mean, "without having its blueprint"? Are you talking about java factories or IRL factories here? Also, __do__ ponder Jon's example.

Comment: @Joy Clearly class B needs to know about class A, at least the fact that it exists :) But it need not necessarily know any details about its inner workings. In `public String returntypeofA() { return "abc".substring(0, 1); }` I don't need to know anything about the implementation of `String` and can still return it.

Comment: How can you drive a car that you haven't built?

Comment: @Kayaman, We are not driving but producing ...! Its about creation of type ..!

Comment: @Joy: you're confusing "creating a new object of A" and "returning an A from a method". The two are completely different things. And __neither__ requires an object to be an A to do that.

Comment: Let's not forget the possibility of a divine explanation for this.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, Okay I can believe your fact for a while...! And how about that if you have class and you want to give privileges to limited number of classes to produce its type..How will you achieve that ?

Comment: Then that's a pretty different question, around access modifiers and packages mostly.

Comment: @MichałKosmulski, That's true, but when you do "return "abc".substring(0, 1)" Its always behaves in way whatever is defined for String class in JVM universe...No...? While writing we dont mention but when we create it checks for the existence...! There is a light which gets lit up in search of the already existence to create type of it.

Comment: @Joy: I can't speak for others, but I have not a clue what you were trying to say here.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, I'm saying when we use String class function, so atleast string class exists already and having method which we are using. So it checks for the existence. I think its all about the existence if we want to produce some type from our zone (class).

Comment: @Joy Clearly you can't have in your method's signature a type the JVM doesn't know about. If you wanted to return an object of a class not known at all at compile time (e.g. loaded or generated at runtime, not implementing any known interfaces), you would have to declare your return type as Object.

Comment: @MichałKosmulski, just tell me one thing, If I create a method(In Class A) whose return type is another class(B), then that return type will point to class(B) object which is not associated with the class (A).  Correct..? And like you said if I dont know the class, then object needs to be created then how would I know the reference name for the same ...?

Comment: @Joy I guess this comment thread is getting a bit too long. You can load classes at runtime without referencing their name in code. You could ask the user to input a jar file name and class name and load that class from the JAR. Only the user knows what he'll enter, your application's code doesn't have the name anywhere.

Comment: @MichałKosmulski: I very much doubt, that dynamic name resolution is what's being asked here. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're are confusing what Objects "are" and what Objects "have/produce"

Let's take an analogy with Humans

A Human is a Mammal so Human extends Mammal

A Human can produce a Wallet. And for sure a Wallet is not a human.

So i could write:

```
public class Human extends Mammal{
    public Wallet createWallet(){
        return new Wallet();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure but to have HumanWallet extends Human would be an extraordinary surgery

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible. Because It is possible to return any type of Object . Object is instance of class whether it is String, Long or any user-define Classes.  It is possible to return instance of class in method of any other class without any relationship between two classes.